# iPhone zoomed out overlapping sprite image

Tags: iphone, css, browser

I have a strange problem with a sprite image. I have sent the exact width/height with overflow hidden it works perfectly in all browsers apart from when zoomed out on the phone it is displaying the line of text above even though it is not viable on any other screen.

It works fine when you zoom in to 100%. Is there any apple specific code that I can add to the head that will prevent this?

Comment: Show me yours (code) and ill show you mine.. I promise. Also some sort of image of this Or reenactment of this problem would be nice as well. ( as in photoshopped example of what is going wrong. )

Comment: I have just updated the questions with a print screen how it looks on the iphone and a link to the development site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i suspected this.

You see, Mobile Safari is not very accurate when it to comes showing background images. ( even when viewing 100% )

So you might wanna put like 2px padding ( in the actual image ) to each separate image. ( So that they have around 4px separating each individual image on all sides. )

This image is the 'culprit' http://dev.equi-trek.com/webapp/templates/images/mainav-sprite.png though Mobile Safari is the real culprit i guess.

Comment: I thought I would have to do this, :-(

At first I thought it might of had something to do with: [code]-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;[/code] although this didn't fix anything.